# como puedo pasar parametros a una clase estatica para crear un objeto con los mismos

Tags: php, parametros

Fichero: “ACCESO”.

```
<?php
if(!$_GET['pagina']){
    header("Location:" . base_url . 'usuario/acceso&pagina=1');
}

$registro = Utils::$registros_xpagina;

$iniciar =(isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$registro : 0;

$tabla = 'notas';

Utils::paginacion($tabla,$iniciar,$registro);
?>
```

Fichero: “UTILS”;

```
public static $registros_xpagina=3;
    public static function paginacion($tabla,$iniciar,$registro){
        $tabla = $tabla;
        $iniciar=$iniciar;
        $registro=$registro;

        require_once 'models/nota.php';

        $nota=new Nota();
        $nota->paginar($tabla,$iniciar,$registro);
        return $nota;

    }
```

Tengo dos ficheros, uno llamado **acceso** que es una vista, donde debo mostrar al usuario con una lista y el otro fichero se llama **utils**, que es donde están todas las utilidades que voy desarrollando para accesar mas fácil al código.

**UTILS** es una clase estática, declaro la variable `$registros_xpagina`, y la recibo en acceso así:

```
$registro = Utils::$registros_xpagina;
```

Funciona bien, pero cuando trato de enviar las variables: 
`$tabla,$iniciar,$registro` de la siguiente forma:

```
Utils::paginacion($tabla,$iniciar,$registro);
```

No funciona… no se si las estoy recibiendo y empleando mal o **UTILS**, ayuda por favor.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no funciona? ¿Qué error te da y qué es lo que esperas como resultado final? También escribe un ejemplo y el resultado que esperas y el que te está dando, todo esto para ayudarte a encontrar una solución

Comment: Vale, creo que está dando un error en una clase llamada Nota, ¿podrías incluir cómo está construida esa clase? Es que no la pusiste

Comment: Hola, el error es el siguiente: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Nota could not be converted to string in C:\ruta....  recibiendo esos parametro en el fichero util, los estaria enviando directamente a otro fichero q conecta con la base de datos y luego se cargaria nuevamente en el fichero util asi: public static function showNotas(){
 require_once 'models/nota.php';
 $nota = new nota();
 $registros=$nota->contarRegistros();
 $paginas = ceil($registros/self::$registros_xpagina);
y lo llamaria del fichero acceso asi:  $notas = Utils::showNotas();